# Need help with an issue in a circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis, circuit-design

Here is a device that is used to switch on/off power supply (240V) via a 24 volt relay. Issue is that R4 (510) and C1 constantly burn up due to overload(?). Can't seem to see what is the issue. Can someone pls help?

[image]

Comment: Whoever drew this has no idea how to design with line voltages to a bridge.  forget this one.  Do not expect to get more than 50mW from this old offline unregulated supply.  In the 21st century we use SMPS or buy one.

Comment: Is this L and N input the full 240V? That's some pretty dangerous stuff you're making for such a casual question... I would recommend starting with something else.

Comment: This is similar to Belkin Conserve socket actually. Those guys also do not have a SMPS.

Comment: If any of you guys do consulting/freelance work on the side, I'd be happy to reach out to you.